# SQL Server 2012 dynamic SQL - stored procedure - getting syntax error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am writing scripts to generate stored procedures within a database whose current schema notation will be unknown (think shared hosting).

I have decided to use dynamic SQL within the stored procedures so that the web application can pass the database schema based on a user defined setting to the SQL Server in order for it to fire properly.

When I started writing the stored procedures, I noticed that dynamic SQL opens up a whole SQL injection problem I would not normally have so I re-wrote the procedure to combat this. However even though SQL allows me to run the script to generate the stored procedure, each time I try to run the test stored procedure, I get a syntax error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

I believe this is to do with the parameter for the schema but I am at a loss as to why this is not working? I am entering the value `dbo` for the schema.

```
/* 
    Name            : usp_GetTestTicker

    Description     : returns test ticker

*/

if not exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects 
               where id = object_id(N'usp_GetTestTicker') 
   and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(150)
    SET @sql = 'CREATE procedure usp_GetTestTicker AS'

    EXEC(@sql)
END
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE usp_GetTestTicker
    @schema VARCHAR(25),
    @TickerItemId INT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql_cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @sql_params NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @sql_cmd = N'SELECT * FROM @schema.TickerItem WHERE TickerItemId = @TickerItemId'

    SET @sql_params = N'@schema VARCHAR(25), @TickerItemId INT'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql_cmd, @sql_params, @schema, @TickerItemId
END
GO
```

Comment: What if you change your EXEC command to this `EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @sql_cmd, @params = @sql_params, @schema = @schema, @TickerItemId = @TickerItemId;`

Comment: you can't pass schema as a parameter. You'll have to build the string.

Comment: Jeremy has the reason. Consider what would happen if you wrote a SELECT statement like `SELECT * From @schema.MyTable` directly. It doesn't work, since you can't have a variable as the schema identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent SQL injection, you will need to validate the schema against the `sys.schemas` table, e.g.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_GetTestTicker
    @schema NVARCHAR(25),
    @TickerItemId INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = @schema)
    BEGIN
        -- throw an error here. Your web code will have to handle the error and report an invalid schema

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @sql_cmd NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql_params NVARCHAR(MAX)

        SET @sql_cmd = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @schema + '.TickerItem WHERE TickerItemId = @TickerItemId'

        SET @sql_params = N'@TickerItemId INT'

        EXEC sp_executesql @sql_cmd, @sql_params, @TickerItemId
    END
END
```